# Compare data between two columns

Tags: r, merge, compare

I have two data sets. 
After merging them by a given ID, i want to compare two variables and report the ID or position where the values aren't equal. i.e. check whether  value `df$b[n]== df$b[n]`

I have tried using `compare`below but it reports `FALSE or TRUE`

```
 x.1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5) , a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=c(1,2,3,4,5))
    x.1
    x.2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5) , a2=c(1,1,2,3,4), b2=c(1,1,99,3,4))
    x.2
    df <- merge(x.1,x.2,by="id")
    comp <- compare(df$b,df$b2,allowAll=FALSE)
    comp
    comp$tM
```

Comment: You might be looking for `which`; `with(df, which(b != b2))`. Please also see the 'Note' section in `?==` about comparing numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your condition in standard `[` function as `i` argument, column that you want to show as argument `j` and `drop = F` controls whether you want data.frame or vector in return in case you select only 1 column.

```
df[df$b != df$b2, "id", drop = F]
##   id
## 2  2
## 3  3
## 4  4
## 5  5
```